# How to bind Borderpane left property to node with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

How would I go about changing the borderpane's left property to a certain node whenever an integer variable is changed? What type of ObjectProperty do I use and how do I bind this as well as listen to the integer variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
IntegerProperty intProp = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

border.leftProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectProperty(
    () -> {
        int value = intProp.get();
        Node node = getLeftNodeForValue(value);
        return node ;
    },
    intProp));
```

Where `getLeftNodeForValue(...)` is just a method that retrieves the appropriate node for a give integer value.

Alternatively, just use a listener instead of a binding:

```
intProp.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    border.setLeft(getLeftNodeForValue(newValue.intValue())));
```